# ARMA modeling in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time series. I want to model it using ARMA, which will be used for forcasting.

In R I am using `arima()` function to get the coefficients. But `arima()` requires order(p,d,q) as input. What is the simplest way in R to arrive at a good value for p and q (with d = 0) so that I don't overfit?

Answer (score 6):

Simplest way to arrive at values for $p$ and $q$ is using `auto.arima` function from package **forecast**. There is no simplest way in any statistical package to arrive at good values. The main reason for that is that there is no universal definition of good.

Since you mention overfitting, one possible way is to fit arima models for different values of $p$ and $q$ and then pick the one which is the best according to your overfitting criteria (out of sample forecasting performance for example). `auto.arima` does basically the same, you can choose between AIC, AICC and BIC to let `auto.arima` pick the best model.

Comment: I will try this too :)

Comment: By changing The number of values "in the out of sample" don't you change the "best model" ?. Isn't this like the tail wagging the dog ? Also what about tests of necessity and sufficiency for the parameters in the "best model"

Comment: @IrishStat, what I had in mind for this example, is dividing the data into train and test part, fitting different ARMA models for the train set and using the forecasting performance on the test set to select the "best" model. I do not claim that this will be the **best** model, only best to this criteria.

Comment: @mpkitas Agreed ! It will be the best model to predict the out-of-sample from that 1 origin , given the criteria. That is an awfully "soft" highly qualified determination of what might be the "best model" .

Answer (score 6):

One option is to fit a series of ARMA models with combinations of $p$ and $q$ and work with the model that has the best "fit". Here I evaluate "fit" using BIC to attempt to penalise overly complex fits. An example is shown below for the in-built Mauna Loa $\mathrm{CO}_2$ concentration data set

```
## load the data
data(co2)
## take only data up to end of 1990 - predict for remaining data later
CO2 <- window(co2, end = c(1990, 12))

## Set up the parameter sets over which we want to operate
CO2.pars <- expand.grid(ar = 0:2, diff = 1, ma = 0:2, sar = 0:1,
                        sdiff = 1, sma = 0:1)
## As you are only wanting ARMA, then you would need something like
## pars <- expand.grid(ar = 0:4, diff = 0, ma = 0:4)
## and where you choose the upper and lower limits - here 0 and 4

## A vector to hold the BIC values for each combination of model
CO2.bic <- rep(0, nrow(CO2.pars))

## loop over the combinations, fitting an ARIMA model and recording the BIC
## for that model. Note we use AIC() with extra penalty given by `k`
for (i in seq(along = CO2.bic)) {
    CO2.bic[i] <- AIC(arima(CO2, unlist(CO2.pars[i, 1:3]), 
                            unlist(CO2.pars[i, 4:6])),
                      k = log(length(CO2)))
}

## identify the model with lowest BIC
CO2.pars[which.min(CO2.bic), ]

## Refit the model with lowest BIC
CO2.mod <- arima(CO2, order = c(0, 1, 1), seasonal = c(0, 1, 1))
CO2.mod
## Diagnostics plots
tsdiag(CO2.mod, gof.lag = 36)

## predict for the most recent data
pred <- predict(CO2.mod, n.ahead = 7 * 12)
upr <- pred$pred + (2 * pred$se) ## upper and lower confidence intervals
lwr <- pred$pred - (2 * pred$se) ## approximate 95% pointwise

## plot what we have done
ylim <- range(co2, upr, lwr)
plot(co2, ylab = ylab, main = expression(bold(Mauna ~ Loa ~ CO[2])),
     xlab = "Year", ylim = ylim)
lines(pred$pred, col = "red")
lines(upr, col = "red", lty = 2)
lines(lwr, col = "red", lty = 2)
legend("topleft", legend = c("Observed", "Predicted", "95% CI"),
       col = c("black", "red", "red"), lty = c(1, 1, 2), bty = "n")
```

Comment: Hi, even I was thinking along similar lines! I have some questions -

Comment: How did you choose order = c(0,1,1) and seasonal = c(0,1,1) for ## Refit the model with lowest BIC?

Comment: @rOOkie if you run the code, the line after `## identify the model....` shows the parameters for the model with minimal BIC. That was the model I then refitted.

Comment: Ah okay, got it :)

Comment: Hmm, interesting: downvote on my answer without courtesy of indicating what is wrong. And the other answer here is effectively the same as mine, but hasn't been downvoted.

Comment: @Gavin, sh*t happens :) For the record, I've upvoted your question, I liked the code.

Comment: @mpiktas - Thanks for that :-) I don't care about the rep or the downvote really - I'm more interested in *why* someone thinks the idea isn't useful. I'm not a statistician so am quite happy to be taught a thing or two, esp if providing incorrect advice.